# Merging tables with same but unequal amount of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

Coffees table

[image: Coffees]

Desserts Table

[image: Desserts]

I want to join these two tables, where the same columns are underneath each other and the non shared columns are filled with NULL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

If you need the results underneath each other, You may try the below query -

```
SELECT MKEY, name, price, station, TempKey
  FROM Coffees

 UNION

SELECT MKEY, name, price, station, NULL
  FROM Desserts;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it!